# Disable block with taxonomies at post page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy

I am developing an events manager for Wordpress.

I have post_type = 'event' and taxonomy 'event_place'

And I want delete block with taxonomy select in post page, because user can do it at custom metabox.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`remove_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box)

```
remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv', 'post-type-name', 'side' );
```

And hook it to 'admin_menu' [as in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box#Example).

```
function my_remove_cat_box() {
     remove_meta_box( 'categorydiv', 'post-type-name', 'side' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

I am guessing a little at the first parameter--'categorydiv'--, but that is what it looks like based on your screen shot.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! `remove_meta_box('{taxonomy_name}div', ....)` is work good!